# php stripslashes not removing quotes and backslashes

Tags: php

We are trying to remove sanitize some input fields Not even sure this is the correct approach. The contact form has 3 fields name email textarea on a HTML file that sends the data to a verify.php file for posting the data. Our question is what are we doing incorrectly with the code below? The code below is all in one PHP file that is called from the HTML file.

```
$name = stripslashes($_POST["name"]);
$email = stripslashes($_POST["email"]);
$message = stripslashes($_POST["message"]);
```

This is the code that does the posting

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$msg = 
"Name: " . $name . "\r\n" . 
"Email: " . $email . "\r\n" . 
"Message: " . $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\n", true);


function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends entirely on what you're trying to sanitise, and what your desired output is. It would really help to give a few sample strings and showcase how they should be sanitised. Having said that, you're probably looking for `strip_tags`, `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge So should we replace the stripslashes with one of the three methods you have listed above Sorry we know very little PHP OR all three applied to the variables

Comment: @ObsidianAge Looking all three up we get the idea still not clear why stripslashes is not working the message field shows in the email with quotes and backslashes

Comment: You've been asked for reproducible samples. Also none of this looks like a HTML email.

Comment: @mario I am not sure what a reproducible sample is? I have tested just now with strip_tags and the quotes and backslashes are not removed It is a contact form from a web page that sends us an e-mail and the message still contains " & / It is not HTML email

Comment: Which part of the [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) or [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes) manual pages indicated that it removes forward slashes or quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're NOT using `PHP 5.4.0+` where `Magic Quotes` feature still stands, then add this at the top of your code to strip slashes from all your incoming `$_` datas.

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```

Remove stripslashes() in the below code so that stripslashing only occurs once:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"]);
$message = $_POST["message"];
```

Comment: We appreciate the answer and will test and up vote it We will post the answer that we were able to make work Perhaps they will stop my down votes ha ha it is an AI that does that

Answer (score 2):

We did a lot of reading over the last two hours and here is code that works
@Karlo Kokkak code as well will solve the issue All code is in a PHP file
the strip_tags and preg_replace with the regex were a few less lines of code

```
if ($result['success'] == 1) { 

$webmaster_email = "tutorial@androidstackoverflow.com";

$feedback_page = "contact-mail.php";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";

$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$message = strip_tags($message);
$message = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $message);
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$msg = 
"Name: " . $name . "\r\n" . 
"Email: " . $email . "\r\n" . 
"Message: " . $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\n", true);
```